# xaml error "Text representation expected for name property"

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to hunt down an error in my WPF xaml code:

*"Text representation expected for name property" line 1*

Can anyone tell me any information about this error? I can only find one other question with the same error message online, and the situation does not apply.

I don't have any blank Name or x:Name properties, nor am I trying to bind to a Name or x:Name property.

My file has 1400 lines of code, any idea how to quickly find the problem?

Comment: Are you binding to .NameProperty for anything, anywhere in there?

Comment: @ChrisW. I would never bind to the name property... on purpose at least! That was the issue though, a binding was in the wrong place. thanks

Comment: Good deal, glad you found a remedy to start the weekend off right! :)